# compare values across rows

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to compare values in the same column/s across rows. For e.g., in the sample dataframe below I want to create a column for price change and populate it as "Reduced"/"Increased" if the price in any year has decreased/increased over that of the previous year.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'Fruit': ['Apple', 'Orange', 'Grapes', 'Bananas', 'Apple', 'Orange',
              'Grapes', 'Bananas'],
    'year': [2015, 2015, 2015, 2015, 2016, 2016, 2016, 2016],
    'price': [5, 7, 7, 9, 12, 9, 9, 4],
    'stock': [11, 8, 10, 6, 6, 5, 9, 12]})
df['change'] = ''

df['change'] = df.apply(
    lambda x:
        'Reduced' if x['price'] < df.loc[
            (df['Fruit'] == x['Fruit']) & (df['year'] == (x['year']-1))
        ]['price'].any() else x['change'],
    axis=1)
```

I am getting an error "Columns must be same length as key". Also even if this is resolved
I suspect whether this will work because of row index.

Comment: post the final expected result

Comment: `df['change']` is not a scalar. Did you mean `x['change']`?

Comment: What's the question exactly? If you want to ask "**How to** compare values across rows", then the answer is "use `.diff`", and there are existing questions about that ([e.g.](/q/57599050/4518341)), though there are specifics to this case that complicate things, so maybe you want to ask something like "How to compare values across rows in groups". See [ask] for tips, like writing a good title.

Comment: @wjandrea - Thanks! You are right, I have edited it to x['change']. As for "what exactly is the question?", well, I am sure there is always a better way to ask the question. I was not sure whether df.apply can actually be used to solve this and ultimately I will use whtever that works. My actual cases are far more complex. Please see my response to mozway

Answer (score 0):

You can use a [`groupby.diff`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.SeriesGroupBy.diff.html) and [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
import numpy as np

d = df.groupby('Fruit')['price'].diff()
# if the years are not sorted
# d = df.sort_values(by='year').groupby('Fruit')['price'].diff()

m = d.notna()

df.loc[m, 'change'] = np.where(d[m].gt(0), 'Increased', 'Reduced')
```

Alternatively with [`numpy.sign`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.sign.html) and [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
df['change'] = (np.sign(df.groupby('Fruit')['price'].diff())
                  .map({1: 'Increased', -1: 'Reduced', 0: 'Unchanged'})
                  .fillna('')
               )
```

Output:

```
     Fruit  year  price  stock     change
0    Apple  2015      5     11           
1   Orange  2015      7      8           
2   Grapes  2015      7     10           
3  Bananas  2015      9      6           
4    Apple  2016     12      6  Increased
5   Orange  2016      9      5  Increased
6   Grapes  2016      9      9  Increased
7  Bananas  2016      4     12    Reduced
```

If you want to compare to the maximum of all the previous years (not just the year before):

```
tmp = df.pivot(index='Fruit', columns='year', values='price')

out = df.merge(
 np.sign(tmp.sub(tmp.cummax().shift(axis=1)))
   .replace({1: 'Increased', -1: 'Reduced', 0: 'Unchanged'})
   .stack().reset_index(name='change'), how='left'
)
```

Comment: Thanks @mozway. My actual use cases are far more complex. For e.g., compare price for any year with the minimum/maximum for x previous years.

Comment: @Nitin then I believe you can use my second approach. But hard to answer without a clear logic description and meaningful datasets to demonstrate the behavior.

Comment: Thanks @mozway. The 2nd approach does not seem to work (for Orange and Grapes instead of "Increased" I get "Unchanged"). Frankly I don't think I understand your solution. Also will be happy if you can take a look at what I found working using df.apply and comment on the pitfalls in that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @mozway,@wjandrea. I could make it work with df.apply! Here is what seems to work. Please point out possible runtime risks in using it.
I understand that this would become far more complex if we get to compare price against minimum/maximum of n number of years. If there are more elegant solutions, I would welcome.

```
df['change'] = df.apply(
    lambda x:
        x['change'] if 
    len(df.loc[(df['Fruit'] == x['Fruit']) & (df['year'] == (x['year']-1))
        ]) == 0  else 'Decreased' if 
      (x['price'] < df.loc[(df['Fruit'] == x['Fruit']) & 
      (df['year'] == (x['year']-1))]['price'].values[0]) else 
      'Increased' if  (x['price'] > df.loc[
            (df['Fruit'] == x['Fruit']) & (df['year'] == (x['year']-1))
        ]['price'].values[0]) else 'No Change', axis=1)
```